# Sunlight + Cave Troll

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In Fellowship of the Ring in Mines of Moria, there was this cave troll who keeps smashing everything. Also in this same room is the Tomb of Balin where a sunlight pierces thru. Why didn't this Sunlight turn the Cave Troll to stone?

Comment: Does the sunlight actually hit the troll?

Comment: Not shown, but the room is very small and when he hits the Tomb, it seems he might have been in the light.

Comment: Are you referring to the movie or is the shaft of sunlight also mentioned in the book?

Comment: Definitely movie, is there a mention of that sunlight in the book?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Trolls in the Hobbit were not Cave-trolls, they were Stone-trolls.  Tolkien covers this in Letter 153:

> I am not sure about Trolls. I think they are mere 'counterfeits', and hence (though here I am of course only using elements of old barbarous mythmaking that had no 'aware' metaphysic) they return to mere stone images when not in the dark. **But there are other sorts of Trolls beside these rather ridiculous, if brutal, Stone-trolls**, for which other origins are suggested.

Lord of the Rings itself mentions many other Troll kinds, including Mountain-trolls, Hill-trolls, and Snow-trolls.  These are in addition to the Olog-hai mentioned in Appendix F (and which only appeared at the end of the Third Age), and also in addition to the "black men like half-trolls with white eyes and red tongues" which came out of Far Harad for the War of the Ring itself.

There is also mention of Trolls in other works, e.g the Silmarillion has the Troll-guard of Gothmog who fight during daylight at Unnumbered Tears:

> There as the sun westered on the sixth day ... it is sung that the axe smoked in the
>   black blood of the Troll-guard of Gothmog until it withered ... Thus ended Nirnaeth Arnoediad, as the sun went down beyond the sea.

Again, these predate the Olog-hai.  All of this makes it obvious that the statements in the Hobbit only apply to the primitive Stone-trolls, and that other kinds of Troll who most definitely *don't* turn to stone also exist.

Comment: But in the movie the Hobbit, they deduced that they have a cave. Stone troll in a cave are not cave-trolls? Well, just one to blurt out this question. Thanks.

Comment: But Olog-Hai were created to be able to walk in sunlight, which implies other trolls can't.

Comment: @Sid - Gollum lives in a cave but he's not a Cave-troll either.

Comment: @Moogle - Appendix F just says that they can "endure the Sun", but that need not refer to turning to stone (much the same is said of Orcs in other places).  Anything more than that is really just fan-fiction from wikis/etc; if you stick to what Tolkien actually says and only what Tolkien says, things look a little different.

Comment: First I think it's more than safe to say the movies are not cannon.  In the book the stone trolls have a cave, but that makes sense because the can't be out in the light and would need somewhere to get out of it.

Comment: Additionally, a small beam of light is not the same as being outside in sunlight.

Comment: Well, beam of sunlight from a crushed/broken rock by Gandalf was the what happened to the trolls in the Hobbit. Not out in sunlight either.